# Committee formation from a mixed gender group with warring parties

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have attempted to solve the following question from Sheldon Ross's *A First Course in Probability: 8th edition (2009)*.

Q. From a group of 8 women and 6 men, a committee
consisting of 3 men and 3 women is to be formed.
How many different committees are possible if 
(a) 2 of the men refuse to serve together? 
(b) 2 of the women refuse to serve together? 
(c) 1 man and 1 woman refuse to serve together?

To begin, I believe we should calculate the total number of committees involving 3 women and 3 men that can be formed from 8 women and 6 men. The total number of committees is $ \binom{8}{3} \binom{6}{3} $. I will then subtract the number of committees which fit the descriptions provided in each part of the question, from this total.

For part a), we calculate the number of committees where the 2 men who refuse to serve together, do indeed serve together. The number of committees where they serve together is $ \binom{2}{2} \binom{4}{1} \binom{8}{3} $. My reasoning: first, we fix 2 of the 3 places on the committee for the warring men. Then, we choose 1 man from the remaining 4 men, and then 3 women from the available 8 women. This gives us the number of committees where the warring men serve together.

The number of committees where the warring men do not serve together will involve subtracting the number of committees where they do serve together from the total. Thus, the answer to part a) is $ \binom{8}{3} \binom{6}{3} - \binom{2}{2} \binom{4}{1} \binom{8}{3} $.

Similarly, for part b), the number of committees where the warring women serve together is $ \binom{2}{2} \binom{6}{1} \binom{6}{3} $. We first fix the warring women on the committee, then select 1 woman from the remaining 6, and then select 3 men from the available 6. Then, we will subtract that number from the total. Thus, the answer to part b) is $ \binom{8}{3} \binom{6}{3} - \binom{2}{2} \binom{6}{1} \binom{6}{3} $.

Part c) seems a bit trickier, but we can follow similar reasoning to parts a) and b). The number of committees where the warring woman and man serve together is $ \binom{2}{2} \binom{7}{2} \binom{5}{2} $. First, we fix the warring man and woman on the committee. Then, we select 2 women from the remaining 7 women, and then select 2 men from the remaining 5 men. We'll subtract this from the total number of committees. Thus, the answer to part c) is $ \binom{8}{3} \binom{6}{3} - \binom{2}{2} \binom{7}{2} \binom{5}{2} $.

Have I solved this question correctly? Is there a more efficient way to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks good.  And the methodology seems optimal.  Personally, I wouldn't write the $\binom 22$ terms (they don't generalize in any obvious way) but it's not wrong to include them.

Comment: I understand, thank you!

Comment: The alternative would be to count directly. For example, for a) you could count the number of committees which have neither of the men and then add the number which have exactly one of the men. I think your way is better for this specific problem because it lets you re-use some work between the three parts, but it's good to be able to do it both ways.

Comment: I understand, thanks @Micah